# integration of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+6x+13}}$

Tags: integration

integration of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+6x+13}}$this is done by [this method](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/system-of-equations-calculator/%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D-6x%2B13%7D%7D) in many of the places.

But my doubt is why I want to use this method.  Shall I use usual integration method? while I am using usual method if it is wrong?

Usual method in the sense function of function rule (i.e.,)

> $(f(x))^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ and use the type 1 integration method
>   Can anyone please clear my doubt?

Thanks

Comment: What is a type 1 integration method?

Comment: $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ formula

Comment: There isn't enough detail.  Why don't you work it out; if the answer matches the symbolab site then ask why your method is better.  If it doesn't match, ask if your method is valid.

Comment: That only applies if the integral is in the form $$\int \left(f(x)\right)^{-\frac12} f'(x)\ dx$$ because chain rule.

Comment: The chain rule is very important when integrating - hence you cannot use your suggested method for integrating. Plus completing the square and using a trigonometric substitution is very neat and easy

Answer (score 1):

You can also directly use
$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+c}}\mathrm{d}t=\ln\left|t+\sqrt{t^2+c}\right| $$
which you can prove by differentiating the right-hand side (or with a trigonometric substitution). In your case, after completing you square, you have $t=x+3$ and $c=4$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to integrate $\int u^{-1/2} du$ with $u=x^2+6x+13$,

you would need to have $du=(2x+6)dx.$

So your method substituting $u=x^2+6x+13$ and using  $\int u^{-1/2}du=2u^{1/2}$ would solve the integral $\int \dfrac {2x+6}{\sqrt{x^2+6x+13}}dx$, not the integral $\int\dfrac1{\sqrt{x^2+6x+13}}dx$.